# 1 hour difference in timestamp/ timestampadd in vertica - Vertica

Tags: timestamp, timezone, vertica

Why there is a difference of 1 hour in timestamp in vertica . Is it because of Daylight savings?
How to avoid that?

Timezone

```
dbadmin=> show timezone;
   name   |     setting
----------+-----------------
 timezone | America/Toronto
```

April month shows correct

```
dbadmin=> select '2022-04-10 09:30:00+0530'::TIMESTAMPTZ;
        ?column?
------------------------
 2022-04-10 00:00:00-04
```

March month shows 1 hour lag##

```
dbadmin=> select '2022-03-10 09:30:00+0530'::TIMESTAMPTZ;
        ?column?
------------------------
 2022-03-09 23:00:00-05
```

I want to go back 30 days from April to March but instead of 2022-03-11 00:00:00-04, I am getting one hour difference '2022-03-10 23:00:00-05', while the same things work well in April-May

April to March

```
dbadmin=> select TIMESTAMPADD('DAY', -1*30, '2022-04-10 00:00:00-04');
      timestampadd
------------------------
 2022-03-10 23:00:00-05
```

May to April

```
dbadmin=>  select TIMESTAMPADD('DAY', -1*30, '2022-05-10 00:00:00-04');
      timestampadd
------------------------
 2022-04-10 00:00:00-04
```

Comment: What's the timezone of your Vertica database? When do you change from daylight saving time and back in your timezone? the answer might lie there

Comment: @marcothesane  TImezone is 'America/Toronto'. It changed on 13 March 2022

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer in the comments.

UTC - Greenwich mean time has no daylight saving time. Your local 'America/Toronto' time, however, has it. So you are 4 hours away from UTC in summer, and 5 hours away from UTC in winter.

Works as designed - or "it's not a bug, it's a feature" ....